# SQL query question: get data from table1 that are not in table2 while table2 is having 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have two tables namely tblStudent and tblAttendance.
tblStudent has columns stdnt_name and stdnt_subject.
tbl_Attendance has stud_name, stud_subject, time_in, date_in.

I want to get the names of the students that are absent on a particular subject in a particular day.

Example:

```
tblStudents
John.     Prog101
Jen.       Prog101
Jimmy. Prog101
Drew.     Prog101
Nemo.   Prog101
Kobe.     Code101
```

tblAttendance

```
John.  Prog101. 10:02am.  10/12
Jen.     Prog101. 10:03am.  10/12
Kobe.  Code101.  10:30am. 10/12
```

Then the others are not in the attendance.

i want the query to show the names:

Jimmy.
Drew.
Nemo.

How do i do this? Thank you.

Comment: sorry i typed in phone so it shows that way

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join

```
select tblStudents.name from tblStudents left join tblAttendance
on tblStudents.name=tblAttendance.name and tblStudents.subject=tblAttendance.subject and date='2018-10-12'
where tblAttendance.name is null
```

Comment: i'm having trouble implementing this. tblAttendance has previous records of the same names and subjects. the only difference in them will be the date_in. Meanwhile, in tblStudents, it can have John. Prog101 and John. Code101 and so on. There will be a user input of SUBJECT and DATE. i can show who are present and who are late in that subject with the same date, but i can't show who are absent. They are absent because they are not in the attendance for that subject and date.

Comment: @JerroldIbañezPetilla, I've modified the answer just include date in on cluase

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested queries also

```
SELECT TBLSTUDENT.STDNT_NAME
FROM TBLSTUDENT 
WHERE 
TBLSTUDENT.STDNT_NAME 
    NOT IN (SELECT TBLATTENDANCE.STDNT_NAME FROM TBLATTENDANCE)
AND 
TBLSTUDENT.STDNT_SUBJECT 
    NOT IN ( SELECT TBLATTENDANCE.STDNT_SUBJECT FROM TBLATTENDANCE)
```

Comment: this shows previous records because tblAttendance can have the same name and subject providing they have different dates. There would be a user input of SUBJECT and DATE and it must show the names of who are present and who are absent. the present ones are easy because they can be accessed in tblAttendance. But what about those who are absent? they are absent because they are not in the tblAttendance. i'm trying to compare the result of the first query (show all who are in tblAttendance in that subject and date) then compare those results to the tblStudents so i can show the absent.